# .NET or Java for web development?

Tags: java, .net

In a scenario where a team want to build a very dynamic, somewhat heavy use interface (with google maps, and some geo capabilities), with lots of AJAX and JS, which is better: Java or .NET?

For the database there's an option between SQLServer and PostgreSQL, and also between Windows and Linux.

The objective is try to find a balance among productivity, maintainability, ease-of-use, 
stability and performance.

So which is better, and why you think so?

Comment: This question is subjective and argumentative

Comment: I think it depends on team skills and experience. .NET team always create better app in .NET than in Java despite capabilities of the platform.

Comment: *puts on flameproof underwear and braces himself*

Comment: As a very very subjective note, I find java feeling too enterprisish for web applications. It just feels too complicated.
That's just me though.
Your first choice should be what your ajax library should be.
And for the love of god don't use something as slow as prototype, pick jQuery, Dojo or MooTools. I prefer Dojo myself.
Just my subjective two cents.

Comment: @Piskvor - I understand the flameproof underwear, but how does wearing braces help?  :-) :-)

Answer (score 7):

> The objective is try to find a balance among productivity, maintainability, ease-of-use, stability and performance.

On those criteria, it probably makes little difference.

The best choice is probably the platform that the team has most experience with.